# Visual Studio Code 1.56 PHP Validation not work

Tags: php, validation, visual-studio-code

When I upgraded the VS Code from version 1.55 to version 1.56 the inline PHP validator stopped working (onType).

I downgraded **to** 1.55 and everything works.

Has anyone had this problem and how can I activate PHP validation in version 1.56?
I tried HTML and JavaScript, this two validators works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PRoblem is fixed in VS Code 1.57